# PHP: Array access short-hand?

Tags: php, arrays, shorthand

In Javascript, after executing a function I can immediately get the an element of the array returned by the function, like so:

```
myFunc("birds")[0] //gets element zero returned from "myFunc()"
```

This is much easier and faster than doing this:

```
$myArray = myFunc("birds");
echo $myArray[0];
```

Does PHP have a similar shorthand to javascript? I'm just curious. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As of PHP 5.4, your syntax for option 1 is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unfortunately in PHP you can only subscript an array variable, no other kind of array returning expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
reset(myFunc("birds"))
```

Will work nicely, although it doesn't work on associative arrays.

Or, of course, you could write a function, e.g.

```
function arr_get($arr, $i)
{
 return $arr[$i];
}

echo arr_get(myFunc("birds"), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

Longer answer is maybe coming soon. See:

- http://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing

Last time I used the [PHP trunk](http://snaps.php.net/), it worked fine.